# bootstrap-vue toggle navigation not removing style attribute when clicked

Tags: bootstrap-vue, nuxt.js

So I have a nuxt application using bootstrap-vue for my navigation bar. When collapsed the element for the navigation adds an attribute called `style="display: none;"` and when the toggle is clicked the style attribute is to be removed however when clicked the style attribute remains so as you can imagine my navbar does not toggle because of this. Now I am using this navigation bar in another component and have no issues. Also it works fine in development. The issue arises in my production set up. I am not sure if it is a configuration issue or a bug but I have not found much on this.

in development I run the build command `npm run dev`

in production I run the build command `npm run generate`

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Here is the code for the navbar

```
<template>
  <b-navbar 
    toggleable="md" 
    type="light" 
    variant="white">
    <b-navbar-brand href="#">
      <img 
        class="hero-logo"
        src="~assets/TraxitHeroLogo.png"
      >
    </b-navbar-brand>
    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse 
      id="nav_collapse"
      is-nav
      style 
    >
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
        <b-nav-item href="#mission">Our Mission</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="/features/overview">Features</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#pricing">Pricing</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item href="#contact">Contact</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="/support">Support</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item 
          class="login-btn"
          to="/login"
        >
          Login
        </b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you reusing the same id("nav_collapse") in both components?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? Facing the exact same issue (working in dev, failing in prod) right now with the most recent release

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the newer releases.